# Bulk Transfer of NFT to Different recipients

Tags: solidity, nft

I am trying to create an NFT auction and can currently receive ERC721 to my contract.

Im running into a roadblock however. Im wondering how to transfer all these NFTs to their proper winners at once rather than manually approving a group of contracts.

```
    function approveWinners() external {
        address[] memory _winners = cManager.getWinners();

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < nftContractList.length; i++) {
            approver(
                nftContractList[i],
                _winners[i],
                nftToId[nftContractList[i]]
            );

        }
    }

    function approver(
        address _nftContract,
        address _recipient,
        uint256 _tokenId
    ) internal {
        IERC721(_nftContract).approve(_recipient, _tokenId);
    }

    function withdrawNFT() external payable {
        address[] memory _winners = campaignManager.getWinners();

        // organizeNFTByFloor();
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < nftContractList.length; i++) {
            IERC721(nftContractList[i]).safeTransferFrom(
                msg.sender,
                _winners[i],
                nftToId[nftContractList[i]]
            );
        }
    }
```

When I execute I receive *Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data*

Is there any reliable way I can transfer multiple NFTs at once to various addresses. Ideally I'd like to get it down to 2 transactions, one to approve each NFT to its respective owner and the other to actually handle the `safeTransferFrom()`

Comment: Is there a contract between the winners? What does `approver` do? Does it approves the recipients? You shouldn't need to approve recipients. The NFT's owner should approve the contract that has the `withdrawNFT` function.

Comment: The contract will own the NFTs. I figured ```approver``` could be called to approve those transfers, but the msg.sender probably wont be the contract so that wont work. Ideally at the end of this auction I want some service like chainlink keepers or gelato to execute a function that will transfer all NFTs to their proper recipients.

Would it be better to use ```transferFrom``` in this case?

Comment: If the contract that has the function `withdrawNFT` owns the tokens then you don't need to call approve.

Comment: Excellent. Will give it a try.

Comment: This is not quite the solution still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it is to create a function that uses a for loop to go through each NFT for transfer one by one.

Can't find a better solution so far. Would be happy to accept any better suggestion than this one.

```
  mintBatch(
        uint256 number,
        string memory nonce,
        bytes32 hash,
        bytes memory signature,
        uint256[] memory nftIds,
        uint256 typeId,
        address to
    ) external payable {
        // The verification part is ignored as it is irrelevant to this question
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
            _mintHandler(nftIds[i], to);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a small (free) tool that helps when transferring multiple NFTs from an ERC721: https://theforever.io/erc721-batch-transfer-tool

When airdropping, you can airdrop to a single wallet and then transfer them out from there.